# Android Broadcast receiver works on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-broadcast

So here is the setup.. I have two apps AppReceiver.apk and AppClient.apk. AppReceiver project has just one receiver and no other activity and AppClient just sends the broadcast message. This works in my emulator with Android 4.0 api level 14 on my mac but not in windows or on actual device.

**Code for AppReceiver.apk**
**MyReceiver.java**

```
  public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            Log.d("MyReceiver", "Got Message");
        }

    }
```

**Manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appreceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.appreceiver.CUSTOM_INTENT"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Code for AppClient**
MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendbroadcastButton);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.appreceiver.CUSTOM_INTENT");
        sendBroadcast(intent); 
         }  
});     
}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.appclient.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

So here is what is happening when I click on the **sendbroadcast button** in my emulator that is running in Mac then I see the log message Log.d("MyReceiver", "Got Message"); in my logcat meaning it is working as expected. I can click more than once and it works as expected.

However when I installed it on the device I do not see the message in logcat (I made sure I am reading the logcat from device) Also I have another windows laptop and on that one it won't show this message on the emulator either. So I am not sure what is going on? Any pointers?

Comment: Did you start your Receiver 'app' once before sending the broadcast? I think you need to have at least one Activity in your receiver app as the latest Android versions require the app to start at least once for their statically registered receiver to be active.

Comment: How can I start the app as I do not want any activity in AppReceiver.apk because launching activity will bring up the gui and the receiver is meant for something where I can't do that. Also as I said it works in my emulator on mac with android 4.0. But not starting it can very well be the problem but how can I solve it with the limitation that I got?

Comment: Try setting your target SDk version in the Receiver app to 10 or below. Check this: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Answer (score 0):

So I confirmed that I will have to start AppReceiver.apk at least once after install and this is a new requirement or safety thing after Android 3.1 as they want user to explicitly start an app in order to user its broadcast receiver.

Since I did not wanted any GUI thing, the way I did is just wrote an activity which is not calling any view and defined the theme as **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"** in manifest so the user won't notice after install that the app has already started and the receiver is also available. Thanks @Nitin Sethi for pointing me in the right direction.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    }   
}
```

Here is how the new manifest for AppReceiver.apk looks

```
  android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
            android:name="com.appreceiver.MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.appreceiver.MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.appreceiver.CUSTOM_INTENT"></action>           
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```